# Most appropriate way of getting absolute URLs from crawled urls

Tags: c#, wpf, uri, web-crawler

Assume that i have root url as follow

```
http://www.monstermmorpg.com
```

Now i will show several url examples and how to get target

```
url1: http://www.monstermmorpg.com/
url2: http://www.monstermmorpg.com/Register#21312
url3: Register#21312
url4: /Register
url5: Register
url6: /Register?news=true&amp;news2=true
// there may be more that goes to same url but i don't have full list atm
```

I need a function that will result following urls as following with help of root url

```
url1: http://www.monstermmorpg.com
url2: http://www.monstermmorpg.com/Register
url3: http://www.monstermmorpg.com/Register
url4: http://www.monstermmorpg.com/Register
url5: http://www.monstermmorpg.com/Register
url6: http://www.monstermmorpg.com/Register?news=true&news2=true
```

There is this method but i believe that is insufficient any better method ?

C# .net 4.5 WPF application

```
Uri baseUri= new Uri("http://www.contoso.com");
 Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri,"catalog/shownew.htm?date=today");
 Console.WriteLine(myUri.AbsoluteUri);
```

Comment: do you need to crawl all the urls, or just extract value? if so a regex pattern will do it

Comment: If you know that you have a base URI and a relative path, then that constructor is the appropriate thing to use. If you think it might fail, use [Uri.TryCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var baseUrl = "http://www.monstermmorpg.com";

    var urls = new string[] {
        "http://www.monstermmorpg.com/",
        "http://www.monstermmorpg.com/Register#21312",
        "Register#21312",
        "/Register",
        "Register",
        "/Register?news=true&amp;news2=true" };

    var absoluteUrls = new List<string>();

    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        if (url.StartsWith("http"))
        {
            var uri = new Uri(url);
            absoluteUrls.Add(uri.Host + uri.PathAndQuery);
        }
        else
        {
            var urlWithSlash = url;
            if (!urlWithSlash.StartsWith("/"))
                urlWithSlash = "/" + url;

            var uri = new Uri(baseUrl + urlWithSlash);
            absoluteUrls.Add(uri.Host + uri.PathAndQuery);
        }
    }

    // Now absoluteUrls contains 
    //url1: http://www.monstermmorpg.com
    //url2: http://www.monstermmorpg.com/Register
    //url3: http://www.monstermmorpg.com/Register
    //url4: http://www.monstermmorpg.com/Register
    //url5: http://www.monstermmorpg.com/Register
    //url6: http://www.monstermmorpg.com/Register?news=true&news2=true
}
```